# Separate string recovered with text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to separate strings recovered with the function text() of jquery.

```
    var gamesOfResults = $('.game').text() + "/";
    console.log(gamesOfResults);
```

For each result i want to add a seperator like "/" to split this string in an array.
At the moment i have this in my console `Rocket LeagueOverwatchLeague of Legends` and i want to have `Rocket League/Overwatch/League of Legends`.

If you have an other technic you can propose

Comment: Can you post the `.game` element? Also, it's weird that you don't have a `/` in your output

Comment: <span class="game"><?= $data['game'] ?></span><br /> in a loop of 3 results so that's why i got this result

Comment: Can't you modify your php to include the `/`?

Comment: oh you give me an idea thanks ! And no because i display this to user but i will do the same with your idea but i dont display it

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```js
var games = $(".game"),
    gameTitles = [], // This gives you more control over the game list
    seperator = "/",
    gameStr = ""; // Create your own fallback

games.each(function(el, i) {
    gameTitles.push($(this).text());
});

gameStr = gameTitles.join(seperator)

/* Enjoy! */
$("body").append($('<p>', {text: gameStr}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="game">Rocket League</li>
      <li class="game">Overwatch</li>
      <li class="game">League Of Legends</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bukharim96/7qcrkgsy/31/).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation of text() on the jQuery-page (http://api.jquery.com/text/).
All texts of the set are getting concatenated.

I'd define a new variable, loop over the '.game's and save the name in the variable.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="gameName" style="display: none"><?= $data['game'] ?>/</span>
```

That's was not hard. 
Thanks @Axnyff for the idea.